# When I am trying to run my bot file from bush console of pythonanywhere I get a syntax error

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

When I run my code on IDE it works but in the bush console of pythonanywhere I get this error:

```
  File "bot.py", line 19
    async def sendMessages():
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the code:

```
import asyncio
import time
from datetime import datetime

from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot('my token')

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

homeWork = False

inputText = "hi"

async def sendMessages():
    neededHourWed = 14
    global homeWork

    while True:

        print(homeWork)

        if(homeWork == False):
            if(datetime.today().weekday() == 2):
                if(datetime.now().hour == neededHourWed):
                    if(datetime.now().minute == 0):
                        await bot.send_message("1296146767", "its wednesday")

                        neededHourWed += 1

        else:
            await bot.send_message("1296146767", "положите телефон в шкаф")

@dp.message_handler()
async def getMessages(msg: types.Message):

    global inputText
    global homeWork

    inputText = msg.text
    print(inputText)
    if(inputText == "/homework"):
        homeWork = True
        inputText = "hi"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop.create_task(sendMessages())
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

How can I fix it? The librares are installed.

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: "bush" should be "Bash", no?

Comment: @darthbaba i tried to use version 3.8, 3.7, 3.6